# How to compile ActionScript projects from Github source

Tags: actionscript, flash-builder

I am new to Flash Builder development environment. I need to use the library below in my project but don't know how to compile it to produce a .swc file. I tried importing the source folder as a Flash Builder project to no avail. Can someone help please?

This is the library I want to use:

https://github.com/fljot/Gestouch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the library with both Maven and Ant, build files are already there, just take a look.
Precompiled SWCs (dev builds) are available here for now http://repository-fljot.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/gestouch/gestouch/